# Map an iterable to non-iterable directly to DTO

Tags: dto, mapstruct

I have been working with MapStruct 1.1 some days now and haven't yet achieved what i need.

What I want to do is the following:
I want to map a JPA-Entity to a DTO to achieve nicer view binding of my properties in a Primefaces project.

So i have my entities as follows:

**Patient.java**

```java
public class PatientEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private long patid;

    // ...
    // countless properties here
    // ...

    private List<PersonEntity> persons;    // contains a history of persons

    // getters and setters
}
```

**Person.java**

```java
public class PersonEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private long personid; // some id

    private String name;

    // other properties + getters/setters
}
```

And i want to map those entities like this:

**PatientDto.java**

```java
public class PatientDto {
    private long patientNumber;

    private Date birthday;

    private PersonDto latestPersonInfo;

    // some other properties + getters/setters
}
```

**PersonDto.java**

```java
public class PersonDto {

    private String name;

    private String surname;

    // some other properties + getters/setters
}
```

I wrote Mapper classes and an utility like it's described in the official examples on GitHub (https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/tree/master/mapstruct-nested-bean-mappings & https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/tree/master/mapstruct-iterable-to-non-iterable) but when I want to execute my test case (simply creating entities, then call the mapper and then assertEquals() the single properties) I get a `NullPointerException` for the PersonMapper but the PatientMapper successfully does its work, except for the `latestPersonInfo` property.

My Mapper and utils look as follows:

**LatestPerson.java**

```java
@Qualifier
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface LatestPerson {

}
```

**PersonUtil.java**

```java
// Returns the one person object i need for the further properties
// returns the latest person object
public class PersonUtil {

    @LatestPerson
    public PersonEntity latest(List<PersonEntity> persons) {

        if (persons != null && !persons.isEmpty()) {
            for (PersonEntity person : persons) {
                if (person.getPbisdatum() == null) {
                    return person;
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

**PatientMapper.java**

```java
@Mapper(uses = PersonUtil.class)
public interface PatientMapper {

    PatientMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(PatientMapper.class);

    @Mappings({
        @Mapping(source = "patnr", target = "patientNumber"),
        // other mappings
        @Mapping(source = "persons", target = "latestPersonInfo", qualifiedBy = LatestPerson.class)
    })
    PatientDto fromPatientEntity(PatientEntity patient);

}
```

**PersonMapper.java**

```java
public interface PersonMapper {

    PersonMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(PersonMapper.class);

    @Mappings({
        @Mapping(source = "panrede", target = "salutation"),
        @Mapping(source = "ptitel", target = "title"),
        @Mapping(source = "pvorname", target = "name"),
        // other mappings
    })
    PersonDto fromPersonEntity(PersonEntity person);

    @InheritInverseConfiguration
    PersonEntity toPersonEntity(PersonDto personDto);

}
```

So, I thought that nested properties get automatically converted but it looks like that they don't in this case, I also get a compiler error that tells me that I need a mapping method for the conversion: `PersonDto map(List<PersonEntity> value)` but I thought, that i already provided this with the use of the utils.

If someone has an idea please tell me or provide tips to implement a good workaround.

Note:
The application only compiles if I change my *PersonUtil* to return a PersonDto and use the mapper that I wrote explicitly but then the NullPointerException gets thrown because my PersonMapper can't be instantiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my solution, I just didn't see that i forgot to annotate my `PersonMapper` with the `@Mapper` annotation.

However, if someone was ever in the situation of the same problem or does need the same function then this approach will work.

Corrected PersonMapper class:

**PersonMapper.java**

```java
@Mapper    // <- I oversaw to add this
public interface PersonMapper {

  PersonMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(PersonMapper.class);

    @Mappings({
        @Mapping(source = "panrede", target = "salutation"),
        @Mapping(source = "ptitel", target = "title"),
        @Mapping(source = "pvorname", target = "name"),
        // other mappings
    })
    PersonDto fromPersonEntity(PersonEntity person);

    @InheritInverseConfiguration
    PersonEntity toPersonEntity(PersonDto personDto);

}
```

Comment: Great that you found the problem and resolve it :). A small plug, currently I am working on an IntelliJ plugin for MapStruct and we are going to highlight code like this with an error saying that the `@Mapper` or `@MapperConfig` annotation is missing.

Comment: @Filip Nice, looking forward to trying it as soon as it will be released! :)

Answer (score 0):

Other way of doing this is, no need to create Qualifier and Utils class.

In **PatientMapper.java**

you can directly use ,

```
@Mappings({
    @Mapping(source = "patnr", target = "patientNumber"),
    @Mapping(target = "latestPersonInfo", expression = "java(PersonMapper.INSTANCE.fromPersonEntity(patient.getPersons().get(0)))")
    })
PatientDto fromPatientEntity(PatientEntity patient);
```